# ImageJ, roiManager("add")

Tags: java, macros, imagej

It's my first question in StackOverflow.

I have a doubt about `roiManager("add")` macro command. I'm trying to insert a macro content inside a plugin but im trying to understand what is *adding* to the roi manager. Here is the code:

```
run("Analyze Particles...", "size=0-Infinity circularity=0.00-1.00 show=Masks display clear record");

for (i=0; i<nResults; i++){
x = getResult('XStart', i);
    y = getResult('YStart', i);
    doWand(x,y);
    roiManager("add");
}
```

I dont sure if the roiManager("add") is inserting the "doWand" result or another thing.

If someone helps me I will be very grateful. Thanks.

**Edit:**
Now I'm trying to develop the Macro with Java classes but I'm not sure how to add particles to the roi manager with the RoiManager class. I put the code here:

```java
ij.plugin.frame.RoiManager roiManager = ij.plugin.frame.RoiManager.getInstance();
IJ.run("Convert to Mask");
IJ.run("Fill Holes");
IJ.run("Set Scale...", "distance=1 known="+pixelSize+" pixel=1 unit=um");
IJ.run("Analyze Particles...", "size=0-Infinity circularity=0.00-1.00 show=Masks display clear record");
// add the particles to the roiManager
ResultsTable rt = Analyzer.getResultsTable();
int nResults = rt.getCounter();
for (int i=0; i<nResults; i++) {
    int x = Integer.parseInt(rt.getStringValue("XStart", i));
    int y = Integer.parseInt(rt.getStringValue("YStart", i));
    int doWandResult = IJ.doWand(x,y);

    //roiManager.add(IJ.getImage(), Roi¿?, doWandResult); //¿?¿?¿?¿?¿
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to add the results of *Analyze Particles* to the ROI Manager, use the option *Add to Manager*:

```
run("Analyze Particles...", "add");
```

Otherwise, you can add single ROIs as you propose, using:

- the **Macro language**

`roiManager(add)` adds the current selection to [the ROI Manager](http://imagej.net/docs/guide/146-30.html#fig:The-ROI-Manager), as if you used *Edit > Selection > Add to Manager*.

In your macro, that means the selection created by `doWand(x,y)` is added to the ROI Manager.

See also the [macro language documentation](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/developer/macro/functions.html#roiManager).

- a **Java plugin**:

I recommend using the [Recorder](http://imagej.net/docs/guide/146-31.html#sub:Record...) (*Plugins > Macros > Record...*) in **Java** mode to get the required code. In a plugin, you could use for example:

```
IJ.run(imp, "Analyze Particles...", "add");
```

or

```
import ij.plugin.frame.RoiManager;

...

RoiManager rm = RoiManager.getInstance();
rm.addRoi(imp.getRoi());
```

See also the [RoiManager javadoc](http://javadoc.imagej.net/ImageJ1/index.html?ij/plugin/frame/RoiManager.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Last night I continued worrking and I developed a little bit the plugin but I dont know how to add particles to the roi manager with the RoiManager class. I will edit the question and I will put the code... Maybe you can help me.

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly. Please notice that `run("Analyze Particles...", "add");` is the easiest solution to avoid the loop in both your macro and your plugin.